# Почему свою линию стали гнуть?

Tags: фразеология

Фразеологизм "гнуть свою линию" часто используется в современной речи.

Но вот в середине XIX века свою линию обычно **вели, но не гнули,** и это выражение является достаточно ясным. Гнуть ее стали уже к концу XIX столетия, вот только зачем?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По всей видимости, выражение "**гнуть свою линию**" соединяет в себе просторечие "**гнуть своё**" (*настаивать на своём*, вопреки кому-то; в воровском жаргоне "гнуть" означает подчинять себе) и канцеляризм "**вести свою линию**" (*вести себя независимо* в каком-то деле), поэтому в производном разговорном выражении "гнуть свою линию" глагол не означает "изгибания линии", а лишь добавляет к независимому поведению значение *противодействия*. Несмотря на то, что все три выражения словарями синонимов объединяются, они различаются по смыслу: "гнуть свою линию" добавляет *систематичности* выражению "гнуть своё", а  "вести свою линию" не делает акцента на противодействии, это выражение формальное и дипломатичное, применимое к себе и своим сторонникам; по отношению же к недругам и политическим противникам предпочитается сравнительно агрессивное выражение "гнуть свою линию".

Comment: Эта гипотеза и мне пришла в голову вчера, но я бы не смог так толково изложить.

Comment: В принципе  такое объяснение вполне правдоподобно, возможно, так всё и было. Единственное противоречие, которое заключает в себе фразеологизм, состоит в том, что стремление не сворачивать со своей  "прямой"  линии сопровождается  необходимостью ее гнуть. А это силовое воздействие может восприниматься именно как отступление от прямой линии.